# jQuery Assign Hidden Value in <table> with Multiple Forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've read several Stack Overflow posts about how you can't embed multiple forms inside `<table>` or `<tr>` elements. That's exactly what I want to do though. Please see the image at bottom for the ideal layout.

Some recommend wrapping the whole table in a `form` tag and submitting the whole thing. Some recommend doing some CSS magic and formatting the whole table in `<divs>` to show like an actual `<table>`, others recommended to make a `<table>` for each form and hide the header on all but the first, others recommended no `<form>`s and just some jQuery magic to detect when any element in the row is changed.

I have a hidden field on the form in each partial, `#Id`, the Id of the `ResponseItem` (the data for the Checklist and Activity), and I want to update the hidden field when the form gets posted. I have an upsert-like controller action that creates the `ItemResponse` if it doesn't exist and updates it if it does. Both return the model's Id and ideally update the hidden field.

**TLDR:** My code works up until the the `formTarget.find(".ModelId").val(data["itemResponseId"]);` line. When I console.log, it seems to find the form, but doesn't update the hidden field. I'm at a loss for a proper way to handle this.

My `<table>` and javascript code if it matters:

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Activity</td>
        <td>Liked</td>
        <td>Tried</td>
        <td>Inclincation</td>
        <td>Intensity</td>
        <td>Comments</td>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    @foreach (var activity in ViewBag.ActivityItems)
    {
        <tr>
            ... partial here ...
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Javascript

```
$(".itemResponseForm").submit(function (event) {
        //console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault();
        var formTarget = $(event.target);
        $.ajax({
            url: "ItemResponses/CreateOrChangeResponse",
            data: formTarget.serialize(),
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);

                //console.log(formTarget.find(".ModelId"));
                console.log(formTarget);
                formTarget.find(".ModelId").val(data["itemResponseId"]);
                console.log(formTarget.find(".ModelId"));
            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        })
    });

$("#Liked, #Tried, #Inclination, #Intensity, #Comments").change(function (event) {
        console.log(event);

        var eventJquery = $(event.target);
        var parentForm = eventJquery.closest("form");
        parentForm.submit();
        //console.log(parentForm);
    });
```

EDIT: Posting my partial -

```
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ChecklistId" value="@Model.ChecklistId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ActivityItemId" value="@Model.ActivityItemId" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Id" class="ModelId" value="" />
<td>
    <img src='~/pics/@ViewData["ActivityItemImage"]' style="width: 50px; height: 50px;" />
</td>
<td>
    @ViewData["ActivityItemName"]
</td>
<td class="text-center">
    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Liked" style="margin-left: 0em; transform: scale(2);" />
</td>
<td class="text-center">
    <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Tried" style="margin-left: .15em; transform: scale(2);" />
</td>
<td>
    <select asp-for="Inclination" class="form-control">
        <option value="playing">Playing</option>
        <option value="watching">Watching</option>
        <option value="both">Both</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <select asp-for="Intensity" class="form-control">
        <option value="0" selected>None</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
        <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
</td>
<td>
    <input asp-for="Comments" class="form-control" />
</td>
<td>
    <input type="submit" data-value="Save" class="itemResponseButton btn btn-primary">
</td>
```

If anyone could point me in a correct direction to get that hidden field updated, I'd be greatly appreciative. Thanks for helping!

[image]

Comment: can you post the contents of the partial youre rendering please? Does `formTarget.find(".ModelId")` return a collection of elements?

Comment: Posted partial. Yes, the`formTarget.find(".ModelId")` results in a  `w.fn.init [form.itemResponseForm]` with all the elements in the form.

Comment: well `.val(value)` definitely works on collections of inputs whether they are hidden or not. that leads me to believe that `data["itemResponseId"]` is undefined or empty. Can you validate the contents of `data["itemResponseId"]` please?

Comment: I think you may need `data.itemResponseId`

Comment: where is `form` tag in your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple forms inside your `table` provided you decorate each outer form element with `form` attribute. Something like this.

```
@foreach(var activity in ViewBag.ActivityItems)
{
   <tr>
      <td>
         <input type="text" name="some-name" form="form:@activity.SomeId" />
      </td>
      <td>
         <select name="some-select" form="form:@activity.SomeId">
            <option value="0">none</option>
         </select>
      </td>
      <td>
         <form method="POST" action="/action/@activity.SomeId" id="form:@activity.SomeId" class="item-form">
            <input type="hidden" name="hiddenId" />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
         </form>
     </td>
   </tr>
}


//js
$('.item-form').submit(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var form = this;
//$.ajax
});
```

and no external / wrapping form.

Comment: You cannot nest `form` elements. Also, there is no `preventDevault()` method on an event.

Comment: sorry for typo.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Where do you see *nested* forms in my code?

Comment: @HereticMonkey, maybe use Google before commenting? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_preventdefault.asp

Comment: @VDWWD Read my comment again. Note the spelling. Google that.